# LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation does not work with cellular network on Samsung

Tags: android, android-location, location-services

I have tested this code which works on HTC One m8 but doesn't work on other devices.

```
private Location getLocation() {
        // If Google Play Services is available
        if (servicesConnected()) {
            // Get the current location
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            }
            return LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(GoogleApiClient);

        } else{
            return null;
        }

    }
```

I don't know if ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION Permission is accepted or not. Here is my Permission List code

```
private void insertDummyContactWrapper() {
        List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

        final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && !addPermission(permissionsList,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
            permissionsNeeded.add("Location");
        if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) && !addPermission(permissionsList,Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS))
            permissionsNeeded.add("Contacts");
        if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) && !addPermission(permissionsList,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
            permissionsNeeded.add("Storage");

        if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
            if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
                // Need Rationale
                String message = "You need to grant access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
                for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                    message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);
                showMessageOKCancel(message,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                            }
                        });
                return;
            }
            requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return;
        }
    }
```

It gets Location when GPS is turned on but when GPS is not available it crashes on the Samsung devices. I just wanted to know if the permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION is get accepted from the user or no.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that to obtain coarse location from NETWORK_PROVIDER:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

// get location from Network Provider
if (isNetworkEnabled) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}
```

The same thing you can do for GPS_PROVIDER:

```
boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

// the same action here
```

Of course you need to set up all necessary permissions etc.

Comment: It didn't work on the Samsung device! Is it that Samsung devices don't work with LocationListener?